# Align secondary y-axis ticks with stripplot on primary x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
labels1 = ['A','B','C','D']
labels2 = ['E','F','G','H']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10,4)), columns=('A','B','C','D'))
sns.stripplot(data=df, orient='h', ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set(yticks=ax.get_yticks(), yticklabels=labels2);
```

[image: Link to chart produced]

I would like to produce some labels on a secondary y-axis that line up with the y-axis ticks of a stripplot on the primary y-axis. I would like E to be at the same height as D, F with C, etc.

I have tried some different methods to align the ticks but having no luck.

Any other suggestions for how to add these labels helpfully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ticks are already set correctly using
`ax2.set(yticks=ax.get_yticks(), yticklabels=labels2)`. What is missing is the limits of the axes. This has to be the same for both axes.

You can either use

```
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```

or go along with `.set`:

```
ax2.set(yticks=ax.get_yticks(), yticklabels=labels2, ylim=ax.get_ylim())
```

Complete example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels1 = ['A','B','C','D']
labels2 = ['E','F','G','H']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10,4)), columns=('A','B','C','D'))
sns.stripplot(data=df, orient='h', ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set(yticks=ax.get_yticks(), yticklabels=labels2, ylim=ax.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Clear solution, so simple when you put it like this. If there are any efficient alternatives that don't involve creating a secondary axis just for the ticks, I would still be happy to hear them.

Comment: While there is the option to label the ticks on the right hand side of an axes, they would always be the same as those on the left. So putting A,B,C,D on both sides, would be easy, but since they should be different here, a different axes needs to be used, like you did here.

Comment: I remember I once made a [feature request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8181) about using the second label independently of the first, but it is still open.